# Do basic questions about Power BI belong in StackOverflow?

Tags: powerbi

When posting a question in StackOverflow you are given the following tip in the Title field: "What's your ***programming*** question? Be specific". Right now I'm sitting on a few questions regarding Power BI (for example how to put labels on the last observations in line charts, if at all possible), but I've been reluctant to post them here since I'm not sure whether or not they would be regarded as programming questions.

Of course I've seen a lot of similar Power BI questions on SO, and the fact that the tag **powerbi** exists does suggest that these questions are allowed. But do they realy belong here?

Edit: I guess I was supposed to post this question in StackOverflow Meta instad. Oh, the irony...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hehe yes truly ironic ...

There is a Power BI tag on Superuser.com that is probably more appropriate for some of what lands here.  My 2c would be if your question involves the New Measure or New Column features (DAX) or the Edit Queries window (M/PQL then it is indeed "programming"

However since I got that up it has gotten minimal traffic as you can see:

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerbi